# count the status types and put totals in one row

Tags: t-sql

I have the following result set

```
Status, Name
0, Type0
0, Type0
1, Type1
0, Type0
2, Type2
```

How do I sum the counts of types and make it look like

```
Type0,Type1,Type2
3,1,1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Name='Type0' THEN 1 END) AS Type0,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Name='Type1' THEN 1 END) AS Type1,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Name='Type2' THEN 1 END) AS Type2
FROM YourTable
```